# How do I tell Google the IP of an Azure Service Bus Notification Hub?

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services, google-cloud-messaging

According to Google, these are the steps to set up Android push notifications on Google Cloud Messaging service:

1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Credentials.
2. Under Public API access, click Create new key.
3. In the Create a new key dialog, click Server key.
4. In the resulting configuration dialog, supply your server's IP address. For testing purposes, you can use 0.0.0.0/0.
5. Click Create.

I have an Azure account with a Notification Hub which will be the server. However, I don't see where I can get an IP address for this. How do I get this piece of the system set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Addresses of Azure Services, such as Notification Hubs, can change as they are scaled up and down and run across different machines.  For that reason, static IP Addresses aren't currently available for Notification Hubs.  Google Cloud Messaging doesn't require a whitelisted IP to create a server key, it just provides it as an option.  In order to use Notification Hubs, just leave the whitelisted IP address box empty, and GCM will allow the connection from Notification Hubs.